# what is ".filename" in the linux and how to open that file?

Tags: linux, file, command

I see these files many times when I use the command `ls -a` . But I want to open that file and access that file. What material contain that file. How it can be done ?

Comment: you mean exactly `.file`? or filenames that start with a dot (`.`)?

Comment: filename start with `( . )`

Comment: These are hidden files. You can often open them and modify them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in linux all files whose name starts with . is hidden files.
these files are not shown when you use 'ls', but doing 'ls -a' shows these hidden files too.
if you execute ls -a on your home directory you will see lot of such files. (.profile .bashrc .history etc)
such filenames are given to config files. so most of these files will be in a text format..and may be in other format depending on to which application it belongs to.

to know the format use the following command `file filename`

to see text files `cat filename`

Comment: thanks for your answer. :) but why peoples give negative vote. I hate that.